# Почему возникает ошибка

Tags: java

Делаю веб приложение на Java c использованием Spring MVC, Spring Security и Hibernate. Когда хочу добавить продукт меня дает такая ошибка

[image: error]

вот это у меня метод который сохраняет информацию

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute(name = "product") Product product, @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile file,@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(imageUploadPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    String picName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
    File picture = new File("D:\\wasfImage\\" + picName);
    file.transferTo(picture);
    product.setPicture(picName);
    product.setUserUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    productRepository.save(product);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

а этот метод сохраняет в базе

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap map, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
    if (userDetails != null) {
        User user = userRepository.findOneByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
        map.addAttribute("currentUser", user);
    }
    map.addAttribute("addCategory", new Category());
    map.addAttribute("allCategories",categoryRepository.findAll());
    map.addAttribute("addProduct",new Product());

    return "home";
}
```

а это в JSP от сюда я даю информацию

```
<spring:form action="/saveProduct" modelAttribute="addProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<spring:select path="category">
    <c:forEach items="${allCategories}" var="category">
        <option>
                ${category.name}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</spring:select>
<spring:input path="name"></spring:input>
<input type="file" name="image">
<spring:input path="description"></spring:input>
<spring:input path="price"></spring:input>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
```

а это метод который сохраняет картинку

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImageAsByteArrayf(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\wasfImage\\" + fileName);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

вот сделаю эти шаги и получаю эту ошибку 
1) запускаю сборку, 2) сборка завершается успешно, 3) запускается контейнер (tomcat), 4) открывается браузер, 5) я заполняю все ячейки 6) когда нажимаю добавить дает эту ошибку а URL такой localhost:8080/saveProduct.
что здесь причина за такую ошибку? спасибо за ответ

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev с тобой все нормально? очки носил?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev что с тобой читай внимательно

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev АЛЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕ

Comment: Даааа, **ru.stackoverflow** не перестает удивлять ;)))